# Whitch flavour should I chose?

Tags: software-installation

I've got a notebook with a AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual-cor processor TK-53 on 1,70 GHz whith 2 gig RAM

Should i pick the 32 or the 64-bit version?

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 64-bit cpu, you should install the 46-bit version.

Even though you don't need it for the amount of memory you have, you might want more in the future, and there is no way to change from 32-bit to 64-bit.

I believe you should install 64-bit systems whenever you have a choice - there's really no reason to use 32-bit.